# android passing textView ID to function

Tags: android, onclick, textview, findviewbyid

I have an `onClick` like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    updateTable(v.getId()); //All ID's are Int, e.g. id=400
}

public void updateTable(int intID) {
    TextView itemToChange = (TextView) findViewById(intID);
    itemToChange.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

So I have the ID of the `TextView` (id=400) how do I change the colour of it?

What I am trying to do is `findViewById(int)` or how can I pass `v` to `updateTable()` and use

```
((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass v into your function, then why don't you just pass v?

```
public void updateTable(View view)
```

You'll still be able to get the id back out with the same function call.
Now you don't even need to do findViewById because you already have a handle on the view. Just cast it to a textView.

```
TextView colorChanger = (TextView) view;
```

Comment: Perfect, these things are always slapping us in the face (maybe its just me....) Thanks.